# I cannot run pst-tree in my TeX Live 2013 environment

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

Why this does not work?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}
\pstree{\Tdot}
{
  \Tdot
  \pstree{\Tdot}
  {
    \Tdot
    \Tdot
  }
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to compile with `latex`+`dvips` and not `pdflatex`.

Comment: You can also compile with `xelatex`

Comment: @Johannes_B Although `xelatex` can often be used to compile `pstricks` code, (and this example will work) it's not a certainty. It's easy to construct examples that will compile properly with `latex+dvips` but not with `xelatex`.

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you hover over the `pstricks` tag you'll see some information about it. If you click on the `info` button you'll see some information. Your question is one of the most frequently asked questions about `pstricks`

Comment: @AlanMunn: show me such _easy_ example which doesn't run with `xelatex`

Comment: @Herbert I've posted an example in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12390054#12390054).

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-tree}
\begin{document}
\pstree{\Tdot}
{
  \Tdot
  \pstree{\Tdot}
  {
    \Tdot
    \Tdot
  }
}

\end{document}
```

and then compile it with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>`.